# Manage double turn of game

Tags: c

I ask you to help today because I can not seem to do something in my program.

It is a turn-based game, I manage this with:

```
player = turn % nbr_players;
```

this is the number of player we play for now

But I would add a condition if we want every person is a 2 turn each time. If someone would have an idea of ​​approach I am taking

thank you very much

Comment: `player = (turn / 2) % nbr_players;`

Comment: If a player's second turn may be forfeit under the game rules, that would make it more complicated. Consider having nested loops.

Comment: Thanks you verry much is that, i'm stupid!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using C (see [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)), you can calculate (zero-based) player index:

```
player = (turn / turns_per_player) % nbr_players
```

where all variables are integer, and first `turn` is 0.

However, this code is a bit tricky. You may think of more formal and human-oriented alternatives of game rules implementation. But it depends on program purpose and scale.